# Multiple join with on and and case returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `apt`.`id` as `aprtid`,
    `apt`.`apt_no` as `aptno`,
    `apt`.`core` as `aptcore`,
    `apt`.`floor` as `aptfloor`,
    `apt`.`bd_code` as `aptbuld`,
    `bd`.`building_name` as `buldname`,
    `rs`.`resident_name` as `rsdntname`,
    `rs`.`resident_email` as `rsdntemail`,
    `rs`.`resident_phone` as `rsdntphone`,
    `rs`.`resident_pic` as `rsdntpic`
FROM `apartments` as `apt` 
INNER JOIN `buildings` as `bd`
    ON `bd`.`bd_code` = `apt`.`bd_code` 
INNER JOIN `residents` as `rs`
    ON `rs`.`apartment_no` = `apt`.`apt_no`
WHERE `apt`.`id` = '8'
ORDER BY `apt`.`id` DESC
```

When I used this query it returning somehow acurate but in join with resident and apartment case it's not matching the and.
Because I have matched on resident and apartment I have same apartment no but both have the different building but as output, it's returning me the result how it possible where I am doing wrong in this query. Why am I getting the result I think and the condition is not working but.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your `join` conditions are not complete.  I would guess:

```
FROM `apartments` as `apt` INNER JOIN
     `buildings` as `bd`
     ON `bd`.`bd_code` = `apt`.`bd_code` INNER JOIN
     `residents` as `rs`
     ON `rs`.`apartment_no` = `apt`.`apt_no` AND
         rs.bd_code = apt.bd_code
```

Or:

```
FROM `apartments` as `apt` INNER JOIN
     `buildings` as `bd`
     ON `bd`.`bd_code` = `apt`.`bd_code` INNER JOIN
     `residents` as `rs`
     ON `rs`.`apt_id` = `apt`.`apt_id`
```

Comment: I need a query with and in on condition multijoin